# for loop onclicklistener

Tags: java, android

This is the for loop for a + and - button which changes a text in a edittext et[] after clicked, there are errors that requires variable x to be declared as final but once x is declared as final, the x++ in the for loop shows another error that require x to be declade without final, what can i do to use variable x inside the onClick?

```
          for(int x=0; x<itemAmt; x++){
        btn[0][x].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int num=Integer.parseInt(et[x].getText().toString());
                num++;

            }

        });

        btn[1][x].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int num=Integer.parseInt(et[x].getText().toString());
                num--;

            }

        });
        }
```

Comment: Please post the **exact** error(s) you're getting.

Comment: What is et? textfields?

Comment: @blackbelt provided a solution, however I don't see the point of your listeners.  They are not doing anything useful at all.

Comment: Please also post the code where `et` is defined and assigned its values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as simply workorund, you can declare a `final` variable inside the `for` loop and assign the `x` value

```
 for(int x=0; x<itemAmt; x++){
    final int myX = x;
    btn[0][x].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int num=Integer.parseInt(et[myX].getText().toString());
            num++;

        }

    });

    btn[1][x].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int num=Integer.parseInt(et[myX].getText().toString());
            num--;

        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: +1 for solving the problem, but the resulting code is pretty horrible and future maintainers probably won't know why it was done this way. In general I'd try to do this in a different way.

Comment: @DavidWasser I agree with you